# cloud zsh `=` notation vs. string notation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, zsh, gcloud

Why does this work `gcloud config list project --format 'value(core.project)'` but not this `gcloud config list project --format=value(core.project)`? The documentation uses the `=` notation. I get the error `number expected` when using it. My guess is that it's trying to evaluate the projection value(core.project) as a number and the `` tells it to evaluate as a string.

Comment: You can use quotes even with the `=`.

Comment: I can never remember a good example, but the ability to specify a long option and its value as a single argument, rather than two separate arguments, is sometimes useful. (Probably something to do with shell word-splitting.)

Comment: Parenthesis have special meaning to zsh. You should write the second form as `gcloud config list project '--format=value(core.project)'`

Comment: Yet another possibility would be `gcloud config list project --format=`'value(core.project)'` or `gcloud config list project --format=value'(core.project)'` or `gcloud config list project --format=value\(core.project\)`, depending on your taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with [`zsh`](https://www.zsh.org/) but the bash returns a syntax error `unrecognized token  '('` if you do this.

This is not an issue with `gcloud` per se.

The issue is that `zsh` (and `bash`) shells have their own interpretation of `(...)`. In bash, this is the command for a subshell.

The solution is to ensure that the flag values are passed to the command as-is rather than be evaluated by the shell.

As @hobbs points out correctly, you can use `'...'` or `"..."` to wrap the flag value correctly without issue. My preference is `--flag=value` and, when using bash, `'...'` when **no** variable expansion is ever desired and `"..."` when it is.

My personal preference is to always use `=` and default to `"..."`

```sh
gcloud config list project \
--format="value(core.project)"
```